# Localization in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have an app where all the user facing strings use NSLocalizableString(). I've never localized an app so I watched WWDC 2018 video [New Localization Workflows in Xcode 10](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/404/). From there I created a new project, a Single View App. Base localization is on by default. On the storyboard I added one UILabel and constrained it in the center of the view. I added an outlet to it in the view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

And I set its text in viewDidLoad:

```
label.text = NSLocalizedString("Hello World", comment: "")
```

Build and run and it works fine.

Now I add a localization. I select the project and add Spanish.

[image]

Then I Export For Localization... on the Editor menu. I open the file through this path:

```
es.xcloc -> LocalizedContents -> es.xliff
```

In there I find the "Hello World" key and I change the value to "Hola Mundo" and save the file.

```
...
<file original="MyProject/en.lproj/Localizable.strings" datatype="plaintext" source-language="en" target-language="es">
    <header>
      <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode" tool-name="Xcode" tool-version="10.1" build-num="10B61"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="Hello World">
        <source>Hola Mundo</source>
        <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
...
```

Then back to Xcode and Import Localizations. Here's the first problem:

[image]

Why is this a Mismatched Translation?

I go ahead and import anyway. I edit the scheme as follows:

[image]

When I run I get "HELLO WORLD". It's uppercase because that's the localization debugging indicating there's no translation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a few problems here. First, when you do `NSLocalizedString("Hello World", comment: "")` what is actually happening is that you try to fetch a localized string with key `Hello World` and since Xcode can't find that key, it returns the key itself, which you set for the label. So, for best practices, consider using a key that doesn't contain a white space on it. Maybe something like `hello-world-label`. Then, it would be:

```
NSLocalizedString("hello-world-label", comment: "")
```

This will generate the following after you export for localization:

```
<trans-unit id="hello-world-label">
    <source>hello-world-label</source>
    <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
</trans-unit>
```

And now you have to add `<target>` tag to specify the actual translation. Therefore:

```
<trans-unit id="hello-world-label">
    <source>hello-world-label</source>
    <target>Hola Mundo</target>
    <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
</trans-unit>
```

Then just import back the localizations and you should be fine.

**EDIT**

After doing that, a `Localizable.strings` file should have been generated. Click on it and take a look into the `File Inspector` on the right side of Xcode under the `Localization` section. You will that the file is only localized for `Spanish`. So go ahead and select `English` checkbox. Then, your `Localizable.strings` will be editable for both English and Spanish, as you can see on the figure below:

[image]

Now you edit the English version of that file for having both languages in your app.

Comment: It works for Spanish. There is no error on import and the translation appears. However, now there is no English.

Comment: I went with the version of NSLocalizedString that takes a default value: `label.text = NSLocalizedString("hello-world-label", tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "hello world", comment: "")` and now I don't need to mess with `Localizable.Strings (English)`.

Comment: How is it possible that Apple does not realize that the `target` tag is required?

Comment: And a large number of my strings are Swift multiline literals. When I change the above example to a multiline literal it doesn't appear in the exported xliff file.

Comment: If you switch to unique keys, as suggested in this answer, you definitely have to unique the default value for English. NSLocalizedString("hello-world-label", value: "Hello world", comment: ""). Also make sure you've turned on Base localization. Your keys will be in the Base, and you'll have a separate en.xliff (and en.lproj folder) for the English. Check out this tutorial: https://ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html